# How to update a components state from outside after ReactDOM.render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I'm rendering a react component like this

```
export class MyClass {
    render(state) {
        ReactDOM.render(<Dashboard {...state} />, document.getElementById("root"));
   }
}
```

The `render` function is called externally by the environment my class is injected in. Although this works fine, the problem is that the environment can call that `render` method again with an other state object. How can I pass that data to that rendered Dashboard component?

I tried to run `ReactDOM.render` again, but then nothing happens. The only solution I found was to remove that `root` element, insert it again and then run `ReactDOM.render` again, but that doesn't really sound like a solid solution to this trivial problem. Any suggestions how to do this?

Comment: Why not have a parent component which renders your Dashboard and use that in the ReactDOM.render .

Comment: At this point it's not state. It's just an object/array you're passing into the component as a prop. How does the state change? Where should it live? What changes it? There are lots of solutions to this, but your example is vague so it's difficult to help. You could use a parent component as Shyam suggests, use context/providers and `useState`, use Redux...

Comment: My React App is running inside an environment which provides me that `state` object. Its that environment which can also provide me a new state object.

Comment: I've updated my question.

Comment: Is there any function that gets called when `state` is changed?

Comment: yes.  I've updated my question a bit

Comment: Yes..... Please understand that showing a solution in the question is not appreciated. If you really use that solution please delete it from the question and add it as an answer. If you want to point out what you do NOT consider a solution, i.e. to contrast against, please make that more obvious and explain the unwanted attribute which makes you reject it, in more detail. For now I will assume the second (i.e. I will not undo the edit), but please make it clearer.

Comment: good point, I rewrote my question